# ksh script equality test in IF statement failing

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, ksh

```
if [[ $TEST = '(0 rows affected)' ]]; then
    echo "NOT FOUND"
else
    echo "FOUND"
fi
```

Just before this I have `echo $TEST` which gives output `(0 rows affected)`

However the script keeps evaluation and echoing `FOUND` which shouldn't be the case.

What am I missing here? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use quoted variable with glob pattern:

```
if [[ "$TEST" = *'(0 rows affected)'* ]]; then
    echo "NOT FOUND"
else
    echo "FOUND"
fi
```

Due to presence of space in variable `TEST` shell treats it as multiple arguments.

Also your `TEST` variable has some whitespace before `(0 rows affected)`.

Comment: Didn't work, when I `echo "$TEST"` I get `EMPTY LINE(0 rows affected)` . Sorry that is hard to format here, when doing that echo I get a blank line and then on a new line I get (0 rows affected)

Comment: ding ding ding, thank you! So adding the wildcards just let it ingore any characters around it. In this case, it sjust whitespace so that works great. Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome. Yes indeed adding `*` on both sides basically matches anything on either side of `(0 rows affected)`

Answer (score 0):

Don't see any issue with your script...which shell you are using I tried in bash, ksh and sh... all are giving correct result.... see below...

```
$cat a.sh
TEST='(0 rows affected)'

if [[ $TEST = '(0 rows affected)' ]]; then
    echo "NOT FOUND"
else
    echo "FOUND"
fi

$bash a.sh
NOT FOUND
$ksh a.sh
NOT FOUND
$sh a.sh
NOT FOUND
```